# Extract type from nested parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to use the value of a function parameter in the return type.
Consider the following function:

```
export function trackKeys(node: HTMLElement, { names }: {
    names: string[];
}) {
    const methods: { [k in typeof names[number]]: (e: Event) => void } = names.reduce((obj, name) => {
        return {
            ...obj,
            [name]: (e: Event) => {
                // Do something
            },
        };
    }, {});
}
```

Here, the "methods" have the type of `{ [k in typeof names[number]]: (e: Event) => void }`, which essentially becomes "string". I would like to have the object keys extracted from the "names" parameter supplied to the function. So that it will be something like:
`{ [k in "john"|"david"|"henry"]: (e: Event) => void }` if the function is called like `trackKeys(node, {names: ["john", "henry", "david"]});`

An example:

```
const obj = trackKeys(node, {names: ["apple", "potato"]});
//Expected type {"apple":(e: Event) => void, "potato":(e: Event) => void};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a generic and pass the array as `const` so its values are fixed as part of the type.

```
export function trackKeys<N extends readonly string[]>(
    node: HTMLElement,
    { names }: { names: N },
) {
    const methods = names.reduce((obj, name) => {
        return {
            ...obj,
            [name]: (e: Event) => {
                // Do something
            },
        };
    }, {});

    return methods as { [k in N[number]]: (e: Event) => void };
}

const obj = trackKeys(node, { names: ["apple", "potato"] as const });
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks. Unfortunately I need the signature to be { names } and not just names, as there might be other parameters alongside, like { names, values, ... }. Let me see if I can find a solution to fix your signature.

Comment: { names: N; } instead of { names: string[]; } solved the problem. Okay wasn't too hard. Thanks for pointing to the right direction.